# Pow (webserver) with directory listing

Tags: webserver, rack-pow

Is there a way to do directory listing with Pow?

http://pow.cx

Since GUI access to Apache is kind of deprecated on OS X. I am looking for a very simple web server setup where I can add random directories and serve up static content that may not have an index file, with minimal hassle and setup.